# duda con la funcion $.get de la libreria jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

estoy aprendiendo javascrit utilizando la libreria jquery, y no he podido resolver el siguiente problema, el cual consiste en un login que pide el usuario y constrasena, y si concuerdan con el usuario que esta definido en un archivo php me deberia mostrar el mensaje de que el usuario es correcto. Sin embargo, eso no pasa. Siempre me dice que es incorrecto:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {


    //NOTA: el comportamiento default de submit, es que recargue la pagina despues de enviar los datos
    $("#login").submit(function(){

        var user = $("#usuario").val();

        var pass = $("#contra").val();

        alert(user+" "+pass);

        //literal: paquete a enviar al servidor
        var datosFormulario = {usuario:user, contra: pass}

        //enviamos el paquete al servidor, y la respuesta se la mandamos a la funcion procesar datos
        $.get("login.php", datosFormulario, procesarDatos());

        return false;//desabilito el comportamiento default

    }); 

    function procesarDatos(datos_devueltos){
        alert(datos_devueltos)
        if(datos_devueltos=="autorizado"){

            $("#contenidos_externos").html("<p> Usuario correcto. Bienvenido </p>");

        }else{

            $("#contenidos_externos").html("<p> Usuario incorrecto. Intenta de nuevo </p>")

        }

    }

}); 
</script>
```

archivo php:

```
$contra_entrar="1234";
$usu_entrar="Juan";

$el_usuario=isset($_GET['usuario']) ? $_GET['usuario'] : $_POST['usuario'];
$la_contra=isset($_GET['contra']) ? $_GET['contra'] : $_POST['contra'];

if ($el_usuario==$usu_entrar && $la_contra==$contra_entrar) {
  echo 'autorizado';
} else {
  echo 'fallo';
}
```

en el alert de la funcion procesar datos, simpre me dice que el objeto esta indefinido, pero por mas que le he dado vueltas no hayo la solucion

PD: tambien soy nuevo en stackoverflow.

Formulario:

```
<div class="contenido">
    <div class="principal">
        <form method="get" action="login.php" id="login">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>                    
                    <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="contra">Contaseña: </label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <input type="text" name="contra" id="contra">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton" value="Enviar" >
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        <div id="contenidos_externos"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: el  alert(user+" "+pass); te muestra los datos cuando los ingresas en los inputs?

Comment: Si, si muestra los datos, ingreso Juan como usuario y 1234 como contrasena para que concuerde con los datos del archivo php, pero por algun motivo me muestra un undefine en el alert de la funcion procesar datos

Comment: disculpa que insista, pero en el tercer parametro debes pasar el nombre de la funcion como referencia sin los () .. ya que jquery se encargara de llamar dicha funcion pasandole los parametros.. aca te dejo 1 link para que veas que la solucion propuesta funciona.. https://7be0989a.ngrok.io/  el link estara disponible por 1 por de horas.

Comment: tienes el codigo de tu formulario??

Comment: el archivo del formulario, el del js y login.php los tienes dentro del mismo directorio?

Comment: Hola, no te preocupes. Acabo de ver tu ejemplo y si, asi tiene que ser, lo raro es que yo le quito los parentisis y nisiquiera entra a la funcion, ya que no muestra ningun alert. No se que podra ser, ya que vi en el tutorial que lo ponian sin parentesis y como no me funciono le agregue los parentesis y me mostro el alert con el undefine

Comment: Si, tengo el codigo del formulario

Comment: Y si, tengo todo en un mismo directorio

Comment: raro entonces... si ingresas directo al archivo login.php te muestra el texto "fallo" ?? ej. tuservidor/login.php

Comment: no sabria responderte a eso porque lo estoy haciendo con dreamweaver y ahi solo le digo que lo corra en tal nevegador y ahi hago las prubas, esta es la url que usa en el navegador cuando lo abro con dreamweaver: http://127.0.0.1:51962/preview/app/index.html si cambio index.html por login.php (http://127.0.0.1:51962/preview/app/login.php) me muestra esto en el navegador: {"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/preview/app/login.php"}

Comment: ahi quede plop, no uso dreamweaver.. quizas tengas problemas con la configuracion de tu servidor.. estará interpretando bien tus php?? si no llegas al php directamente quizas desde el js tampoco lo hagas.. si inspeccionas elementos en el navegador t muestra algun errror??

Comment: Eso si no lo se, no tengo idea si estara leyendo bien el php, hay alguna forma de darme cuenta? como con algo similar a un alert dentro del php?

Comment: con un <?php echo "hola"; ?> bastaría.. y por url tienes que acceder al archivo

Comment: Y en la consola de firefox todo bien, me acabo de dar cuenta que, apesar de que no entra a la funcion procesar_datos, si le cambio el nombre a la funcion me lanza un error de que la funcion procesar_datos no esta definida, osea que apesar de que no entra como que si sabe que existe

Comment: como te fue? prueba tambien lo siguiente.. como tercer parametro pasa la funcion completa de la siguiente forma:
        $.get("login.php", datosFormulario, function (datos_devueltos){

            alert(datos_devueltos)

    });

Comment: El `alert(datos_devueltos)` ¿no muestra nada en pantalla? Si no muestra aunque sea `fallo` significa que el PHP no se está ejecutando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de batallar un poco, di con la solucion. El asunto es que, no se por que, en dreamweaver no funciona, asi de simple. Entonces utilice XAMPP para crear un servidor local y hacer las pruebas con ese programa, y enigmaticamente si funciona. El codigo estaba bien (con la excepcion de los parentesis en la llamada a la funcion procesar_datos), simplemente que en dreamweaver no funciona. No se el motivo, pero queria hacerlo saber. De antemano muchas gracias a los que me trataron de ayudar, se les agradece!!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba eliminando los () cuando llamas a procesarDatos dentro del $.get

```
$.get("login.php", datosFormulario, procesarDatos);
```

Comment: Si lo hago no entra a la funcion, con los parentesis si entra. Lo se porque con los () me muestra el alert que dice "undefine" y si los quito no muestra nada, osea no entra

Comment: borraste la caché del navegador despues de hacer la modificación? hice una copia local  y si me funciona

Comment: Lo abri con el navegador Edge, el cual nunca uso para hacer las pruebas (uso firefox) y me muestra lo mismo, undefine

Comment: Toma como práctica agregar un dato extra a los datos a pasar, en cualquier solicitud, formado por una clave (sin sentido para el proceso) como "rompercache" y cuyo valor sea una **cadena aleatoria**, de modo que el navegador crea estar pasando un valor diferente todas las veces. Eso te ahorrará muchos dolores de cabeza y pruebas en las que no se percibe el efecto de los cambios en el código.

Answer (score 0):

El código JS debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
$.get("login.php", datosFormulario, procesarDatos);
```

Si llamas a procesarDatos seguido de (), estas pasando el resultado de la función en vez de la referencia a la misma.

La función no es llamada porque estas enviandola para manejador del evento "success" que solo se ejecutará con una respuesta correcta de la solicitud.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType

Para ver exactamente lo que ocurre debes abrir la **herramienta de desarrollo** de tu navegador (Habitualmente pulsado F12) y desde el panel de red (network) para ver el estado y respuesta de tu solicitud con **$.get**

Aún así, no es nada recomendable enviar mediante una petición GET los credenciales de los usuarios, debes tratar de utilizar siempre el intercambio de datos a través de POST, GET no queda protegido por los certificados SSL ya que envia la información de forma legible en la URL del la petición.

Modifica tu script para emplear el siguiente método.

```js
var datosFormulario = {usuario:'usuario', contra: 'psw123'}
    console.log('Validando credenciales.');
     $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "login.php",
     data: datosFormulario
     })
     .done(function( srvdata ) {
        console.log(srvdata);
     })
     .fail(function( jqXHR ) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
     })
     .always(function() {
      console.log('Respuesta a credenciales recibida');
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Recuerda actualizar tu script php login.php sustituyendo $_GET por $_POST.

Ej

```
$_POST['usuario']
```